# plotly does not show titles of multiple plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to layout 2 plots together using `ggplot2` and `plotly`. Here's what I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

mt_mpg <- ggplot(data = mtcars)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mpg))+
  ggtitle("mpg vs cyl")

mt_disp <- ggplot(data = mtcars)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = disp))+
  ggtitle("disp vs cyl")

subplot(mt_mpg, mt_disp)
```

Everything works great but the title of the combined plot only contains "disp vs cyl". I want to include both titles on the top of their corresponding plots. But I don't see any option in `subplot()` command to do so. Any ideas how this can be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is to use `facet_wrap` instead of `ggtitle`. For example:

```
df <- mtcars
df$lab1 <- 'mpg vs cyl'
df$lab2 <- 'disp vs cyl'

mt_mpg <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mpg))+
  facet_wrap(~lab1)

mt_disp <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = disp))+
  facet_wrap(~lab2)

subplot(mt_mpg, mt_disp)
```

Cheers,

Branden